# MODx caches what it shouldn't

Tags: modx

I'm working with MODx revo. I wrote a snippet called putBoxId with the following content:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;

if (!is_null($id)) {
    return $modx->getChunk($tpl, array('id' => $id));
}

return '';
```

I use it like this: `[[~3[[!putBoxId? &tpl='boxIdUrl']] ]]` (with backticks, of course), where boxIdUrl is the chunk with the following content:

```
? &id=`[[+id]]`
```

The problem is, for some reason it gets cached. I tried putting '!' In all combinations, still gets cached. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [[~3 is being cached,  so your putBoxId is actually called only the first time.

In Revo - **any** **[[** (*tag*) can start with a **!** (*non-cacheable flag*).    <strike>So, in your case -  **[[!**~3[[!putBoxId? &tpl='boxIdUrl']] ]]</strike>     (***note:*** there's a typo here and in your original question, see comment below.   this should work:  [[~3]][[!putBoxId? &tpl='boxIdUrl']])

more info [here](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Tag+Syntax#TagSyntax-StructureofaTag)

---

Even better -  unless there's a good reason, get rid of that chunk, as the $modx->getChunk call wouldn't be cached in your scenario (*goes to db to get template, etc...*).

Do it all in the snippet itself using [modx->makeUrl](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/modX.makeUrl)  *(see link for more options)*

```
<?php
$resourceId = $modx->getOption('resourceId', $properties, $modx->resource->get('id'));  // get resourceId from snippet, default to current
$args = (!empty($_REQUEST['id']))? array('id'=>$_REQUEST['id']) : '';
return $modx->makeUrl($resourceId, '', $args);
```

Call like this:

```
[[!putBoxId]] or [[!putBoxId? &resourceId=`3`]]
```

Comment: I tried [[!~3[[!putBoxId? &tpl='boxIdUrl']] ]], it didn't work (unless I'm missed something).

Comment: yea.. that's a typo.    you need to close the tag first:
 [[~3]][[!putBoxId? &tpl='boxIdUrl']]
as your original snippet just adds text after the link.

Comment: just note that your original snippet would fail in cases there's a querystring already,  for example when not using friendly urls.   (just because of the ? vs &)